# Psql - 'database does not exists' while it does and was created in Valentina Studio

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, localhost, valentina-studio

I have started to learn about SQL and installed Valentina Studio & PSQL on my Ubuntu.

I have defined a password via `sudo -u postgres psql postgres` and then `\password postgres`.

Then I have entered `Valentina Studio` and connected to this server with 'discover localhost server`- it found the`PostgresSQL` and I entered the password that I set up before in the terminal and it looked ok and like it was connected.

I have created 4 empty new databases in the `VStudio` and tried to import to them some databases which are located on my desktop.

I got the `database does not exist` while it sure does as you can see in the screenshot.
When I tried to do the same with `template1` the skelton database of psql, it worked.

But why the Vstudio and the PSQL are not connected to each other?

[image]

Comment: You specified `Employees` for `-d`, but the database in the server is misspelled as `Empolyees`. You also want to get rid of the objects you added to `template1` otherwise they will show up in any new databases you create as `template1` is the default template for new databases.

Comment: oh man, I swear I looked for typos and did not see anything. Sorry for the trouble. 
How can I get rid of the objects that I added to `template1`? Can i just delete this database? I can't see it in the VStudio as well as you can see, I can see only the ones that were created by me.

Comment: It will be easier to use `psql`(which is true of most things).  At this point the easiest solution would be to recreate `template1`. See [Template DBs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html). Look for the **NOTE** at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of recreating `template1` database in `psql` as `postgres` user.

```
update pg_database set datistemplate = 'f' where datname = 'template1';
drop database template1;
create database template1 template template0 is_template true ;
```

Comment: thank you.
eventually I went with `pg_dump` and then `init db`.
is there any cons to what I did? or my way and your way have the same effect?

Comment: `initdb` will only work if you removed the old `PGDATA` directory, in which case it would create a new cluster with a clean `template1`. It is the nuclear option. What did you dump with `pg_dump` and did you use that or `pg_dumpall`? If `pg_dumpall` you put back the contents of the old `template1`. Best to verify what is in the new `template1`.

Comment: the problem is I can''t see `template0` or `template1` in the `vstudio` I use.. but thanks I did what you told me. I did use 'pg_dumpall'. I thought that `dumpall` deletes all databases and then `initdb` creates the skelton dbs again (`template0` and `template1`)

Comment: Don't use `vstudio` use `psql`. [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pg-dumpall.html) backs up all the databases, with exception of `template0`,  to a text file. If you then use that text file to restore to the new cluster you will get back the contents of the old `template1` database as it was when you dumped it, in your case with the objects you added.

Comment: If you want to use `vstudio` to see system databases see this [Postgres preferences](https://valentina-db.com/docs/dokuwiki/v11/doku.php?id=valentina:products:vstudio:help:dialogs:preferences:postgresql_server) and check `Show System Databases` and `Show System Schemas`.